# How can I display specific collection?

Tags: html, css, shopify, themes, liquid

For the first part I was able to get and display the name and description of the collection by using this code:

```
<h2>{{ section.settings.title }}</h2>
  {%- if section.settings.description != blank or section.settings.show_description and section.settings.collection.description != empty -%}
    <div>
      {%- if section.settings.show_description -%}
        {{ section.settings.collection.description }}
      {%- else -%}
        {{ section.settings.description -}}
      {%- endif %}
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
```

and I am trying to display the selected collection that I choose in customizer which the the "Featured Collection" and be able to display it in my page. But with this code:

```
  {% for collection in collections %}
    <h2>{{ collection.title }}</h2>
    {% unless collection.description == blank %}
      <p>{{ collection.description }}</p>
    {% endunless %}

    {% for product in collection.products %}
      {% if product.image %}
        <img
          src="{{ product | img_url }}">
      {% endif %}
      <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
      <p>{{ product.price | money }}</p>
    {% else %}
      <p>There is no product in {{ collection.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

It display all collections that I created such a For Men, For Women, etc. But I only want to display the "Featured Product" collection. How can I display the "Featured Product" only?

Comment: Please supply a minimal reproducible example of your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assune you using the following [collection](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#collection) input to Shopify theme.

[image]

using the following schema

```
{
  "type": "collection",
  "id": "collection",
  "label": "Collection"
}
```

To get the same into liquid code you use directly like this way, beacuase it return the collection object.

[image]

`section.settings.collection.products` to get the products from selected collection.

```
{%- for product in section.settings.collection.products -%}
  // use product to display desired data inside loop for each product
{%- endfor -%}

Let me know, if this will helps you.
```

Comment: Mark as answer if it deliver the purpose, it helpful for other in future also